# I am getting Cmake compiler error "-lc++ and -lSystem"

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang

Im trying to compile an c++ code using CMake but Im facing these errors ?

Couldnt manage to find any related content for these 2.

CMakeError.log is:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Checking whether the ASM compiler is GNU using "--version" did not match "(GNU assembler)|(GCC)|(Free Software Foundation)":
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Im using Mac, OS X version: 11.0.1 and Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)

Thanks in advance, but Im probably going to need some extra detailed information since it seems like not gonna get fixed by a simple version update..

Comment: Most likely you have installed only the compiler and not the whole development package

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please, post **actual** error message, which is shown in the output of cmake. Content of `CMakeError.log` is secondary.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Seeing the same on latest Big Sur + Apple LLVM 12, both with Xcode and CommandLineTools.
Not entirely sure if this is simply a bug with CMake though, as there are several libraries it can't find by default, which has worked fine before.